# Problem when using fork() in a GTK+ program

Tags: linux, process, gtk, fork

I wrote a program like below:

```
GtkWidget *pbar1, pbar2;

ginit update_p_bar(gpointer pbar)
{
    // get the value of process bar *pabr*, add it by 0.05, then set the
    // process bar's value to the new value
}

void fork_me(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        fprintf(stdout, "fork() error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
        gtk_timeout_add(100, update_p_bar, pbar2);
    }
    else{
        gtk_timeout_add(100, update_p_bar, pbar1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    // create a new window, add two process bar *pbar1*, *pbar2* and 
    // a button *button* to it.
    // connect *button* with function *fork_me*

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main ();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is show two process bar increase at the same time.
But when I run it, it says:

> The program 'process' received an X
>   Window System error. This probably
>   reflects a bug in the program. The
>   error was 'BadIDChoice (invalid
>   resource ID chosen for this
>   connection)'.

and

> The program 'process' received an X
>   Window System error. This probably
>   reflects a bug in the program. The
>   error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap
>   or Window parameter)'.

What's wrong with my program?

Answer (score 0):

The error looks quite unrelated to your fork. Don't connect your signals and try again, to see if the bug still happens (in this case the problem is in `main`), or if it's related to the callbacks code.

Moreover, your update_p_bar doesn't respect the [GSourceFunc](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFunc) prototype. It should be

```
gboolean update_p_bar (gpointer pbar)
```